# gcloud dataflow component time required

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

Can anyone please help me to point to a tool which could be used to measure the time spent on individual components of a gcloud dataflow? Also if the tools exists, can you please share the link too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any external tool used to measure a dataflow job's components; however, I think this information can be retrieved by using the [Monitoring UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf) that contains detailed information about the general [pipeline job execution](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf#viewing-a-pipeline), as well as the **Total Execution Time** per step. Additionally, you can take a look in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/understanding-timing-in-cloud-dataflow-pipelines) that contains a **Understanding timing** guide in case you want to get a deeper understanding of this feature.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. But the document you mentioned in "link" is for batch processes only where total execution time can be ascertained by the dataflow pipeline. However, I have a streaming pipeline for which I can view only system lag or system_watermark_lag. Can you please tell me how to go about this problem, since I have been struggling with it for quite a bit of time.

Comment: I think that the **Monitoring UI** and [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stackdriver-monitoring) are the only available methods that you can use to get detail information about the pipeline executions. In case none of these options are helpful for your end, you can use the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) tool in order to [raise a Dataflow feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1100337) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.